# Make tag helpers view horizontal instead of vertical

Tags: c#, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-core

How do I display tag helpers in MVC .NET Core 2 in a horizontal wide row instead of vertical?

**Current Vertical:**

[image]

**Expected Horizontal:**

[image]

```html
@model ProductViewModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Edit";
}

<h2>Edit</h2>
<h4>Product</h4>
<hr/>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <form asp-action="Edit">
      <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
      <input type="hidden" asp-for="ProductId" />
      <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="ProductName" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="ProductName" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="ProductName" class="text-danger"></span>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Quantity" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="Quantity" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Quantity" class="text-danger"></span>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
      </div>
```

I'm creating an electronics store test case.

Comment: Hi John, can you embed the pictures in the actual question, for some reason I cannot, thanks, trying to remove the picture links

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, it is a bootstrap CSS question. You need to mark your `<form>` tag as **row** and individual form-group elements as **columns**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Edit" class="row">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <input type="hidden" asp-for="ProductId" />
            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                <label asp-for="ProductName" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="ProductName" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="ProductName" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                <label asp-for="Quantity" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Quantity" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Quantity" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you! accepted answer and gave points, feel free to thumbs up question also